# Oque está faltando?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    $teste = $_POST['Nome'];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>O</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="f_cad" method="POST"/>
        <input type="text" name="Nome"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice: Undefined index: Nome in D:\wamp\www\cursophp\all.php on line 2

Oque está faltando? Está tudo certo.

Comment: "*- Está tudo certo*" está mais errado do que certo. Senão estaria, pelo menos, funcionando. Não é?! A mensagem de erro quer dizer que, se o índice `Nome` não está definido, você deveria defini-lo ou então "checar se ele está definido".

Comment: Tem outros probleminhas no código, mas seria bom começar eliminando essas coisas de XML fechando indevidamente as tags (`/>`) e apesar do HTML5 ser permissivo (o que considero um defeito da especificação), compensa fazer certinho e fechar o form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formulário precisa "abraçar" os componentes que deverão ser enviados ao servidor.

```
<form name="f_cad" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="Nome" />
</form>
```

Para testar faça assim.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Nome'])) {
    print "Foi recebido :: " . $_POST['Nome'];
} else {
    print "Nada foi Recebido";
}
?>
```

Comment: Calma ai, eu fui testar e deu erro

Comment: Bom, o teste em php funcionou, o script imprimiu na tela "Nada foi recebido", mesmo tendo o mesmo nome, em name, e na $_POST. Acho que vou tentar o método GET.

Answer (score 1):

O código está a funcionar perfeitamente, o warning aparece porque na altura em que abres a página ainda não submeteste o form pelo que a variável $_POST['Nome'] ainda não existe.

No teste sugerido em cima, vai-te aparecer "Nada foi recebido" se ainda não submeteste o form em vez do warning que te dava e a partir do momento que o submetes, ou seja, a partir do momento em que envias uma váriavel $_POST['Nome'], ele vai-te dar o resultado na tela.

Espero que tenhas percebido